# problem in realizing "piece of cake"

Tags: information-theory

I have a problem in realizing of this question. As it is mentioned in the picture, we have a cake which is sliced roughly in half, the largest part being chosen each time and the other pieces discarded. I cannot understands the proportions it considers for a random cut:

[image]

And why it just considers 2/3 and 3/5 in computing the E[log *C1*] ? Where are 1/3 and 2/5?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please consider learning MathJax typesetting and also including as much as possible of the questions you ask onto the site and avoid external links. Also please show any own attempts you've done (especially in case it looks like it could be a homework problem).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I wanted to add a picture and since i'm new it said i cannot do this until my reputation is 15, so a link was created. The solution is written in the picture too, but i had a problem understanding it.

Comment: $1/3$ and $2/5$ aren't there because according to the terms of the problem, they are literally discarded.

Comment: I added the picture for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's basically what's going on in this problem: At each turn, the cake is replaced by some portion of it, which is either $2/3$ (with probability $3/4$), or $3/5$ (with probability $1/4$).  The other pieces are always discarded.

Suppose that it was always $2/3$ (with probability $1$).  Then each turn, the cake would be $2/3$ of its previous size, which means that after $k$ turns, it would be $(2/3)^k$ of its original size:

$$
\text{Size}_k = \text{Size}_0 \left(\frac23\right)^k
$$

or equivalently,

$$
\frac{\text{Size}_k}{\text{Size}_0} = \left(\frac23\right)^k
$$

However, the actual situation is that $1/4$ of the time, the ratio is $3/5$.  That means that of the $k$ fractional factors on the right-hand side, about a fourth of them are $3/5$ and not $2/3$.  Heuristically,

$$
\frac{\text{Size}_k}{\text{Size}_0} \sim \left(\frac23\right)^{3k/4}\left(\frac35\right)^{k/4}
$$

where I intend the $\sim$ to mean that "varies approximately as".  If you take the log of both sides, you get

$$
\log \frac{\text{Size}_k}{\text{Size}_0} \sim \frac{3k}{4} \log \frac23 + \frac{k}{4} \log \frac35
$$

and then dividing both sides by $k$ gives you the provided solution (provided you replace the informal $\sim$ with a more rigorous limit demonstration).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was clear and perfect.